# SQL Server database files (.mdf, .ldf) not protected against deletion

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed on Windows 7.

I created a database by using SQL Server Management Studio remotely, now the `.mdf` file and `.ldf` file are not protected against rename, move, copy and delete, those are simply deleted even though the SQL Server service is running.

How can I solve this (protect against deletion)?

Thank you all

Comment: Thank you 'marc_s' for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn AUTOCLOSE option for the database OFF and set folder security, that's all.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your answer is very useful and simple way. (I cant vote it up because i'm new)